# How can I use my Xbox One S controller via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, games

I got an Xbox One S controller as a gift for Christmas and I found out that it can connect to a PC with Bluetooth. It's supposed to work on Windows 10 but it doesn't work on my Ubuntu PC. It shows up as an option in the Bluetooth settings but when I connect to it it just instantly loses connection. How can I use the controller via Bluetooth on my Ubuntu 17.10 PC? I would like to use it for emulators and maybe even Steam games.

Comment: For those looking for an up to date solution (as of January 2022) see this answer https://superuser.com/a/1653276/518572

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To solve your problem:

1. Install sysfsutils

   ```
   sudo apt install sysfsutils
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/sysfs.conf` (as admin), add this line at the end of the file:

   ```
   /module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm=1
   ```
3. Save changes and restart

Reference:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2339212

Comment: It still doesn't connect to the controller. The light on the controller never stops flashing and the PC always disconnects from the controller immediately.

Comment: Okay, this half worked. After trying a few times the controller did finally pair. The problem is that it doesn't show up as a controller in the emulator. Also, I tried running my Blender Game that I made that supports Xbox One controller input and even that didn't recognize my controller. How do I get programs to recognize the controller as a controller?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/set-up-xbox-one-controller-ubuntu/) link, hope it works.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried doing everything that you said to do in your answer again and now it works 100% correct! Thank you so much! This will be really helpful!

Comment: The solution for arch based distros: "edit /etc/default/grub and add the kernel flag 'bluetooth.disable_ertm=1' to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line. Then run 'sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg' and reboot." After this, you should be able to pair your gamepad.

Comment: You can do `echo 1 |sudo tee /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm` and disable/enable bluetooth to immediately apply the change until the reboot.

Comment: @CadenMitchell Had the same problem after disabling ertm, figured out that if you tried to setup the controller before disabling ertm, you will have to remove the controller completely (ubuntu settings -> bluetooth -> click on controller -> remove device) and set it up again, otherwise it will continue to disconnect.