# Rocket League for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: games

I wanted to know how to install free rocket league for Ubuntu 18.04 with multiplayer and DLCs. I know the question isn't specifically about ubuntu but if you know a place please tell me. Bye!

PD: what   is Wine?

Comment: What do you mean by “free” rocket league? Afaik there’s no free trial.

Comment: It is not free. If you already own it in Steam, you can simply install it in the native Steam client, and start playing. If you want the game and all DLC, you'll have to pay for it.

Answer (score 3):

I've installed Rocket League in Ubuntu 18.04 and I runs like a charm - better than in Windows 10, actually. I can even use my xbox one S controller (with bluetooth)!

In order to install it just install steam first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt install steam
```

Make sure you open steam through the terminal (just type `steam`) the first time you do it. Otherwise, you might not see anything happening while it's loading and you'll think it's not started.

After this you may close steam and run it from the 'Activities' menu: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  and type `steam`

Then you just need to install it through steam. (I assume you all know how to do that)

To install the controller you just need to to this in your command line:

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
sudo nano /etc/sysfs.conf
```

and add this line to the end:

```
module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm=1
```

Now, save and restart.

*References:*

- https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
- [How can I use my Xbox One S controller via bluetooth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998144/how-can-i-use-my-xbox-one-s-controller-via-bluetooth)

Comment: "Notice: At the request of the publisher, Rocket League® is unlisted on the Steam store and will not appear in search." :(

Answer (score 0):

Wine is a compatibility layer to allow windows programs to run on linux (with varying amounts of success). You won't be able to get RL working on linux without buying it on Steam and even then there could be some complications.