# My xbox controller doesnt appear on bluethooth settings

Tags: bluetooth

I want to conect my xbos one controller to the computer but i've searched about this and some guy said that you only need to press a buttom on the controller and right away it will appear on bluethoth settings but mine doesn't and i have installed a few things but it wont appear there.

Comment: To start with, 1) which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? 2) Please open a terminal window and run `dmesg | grep Blue` then highlight the results, copy that text, come back here, click [edit], and paste the result into your question.

Comment: does this work for you? https://askubuntu.com/questions/998144/how-can-i-use-my-xbox-one-s-controller-via-bluetooth